# how to pass a value from strong typed View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Shortly my question is this:**
I have a View - strongly typed to the model task.
I have a form in the view that later will pass to the controller.
I want to assign a value to task.CreationUserId in the View. The value came to the view using ViewBag but it is not important
How do i do it? What is the syntax?

**If you want to read the whole story:**

I have a view to create a task. The view is strongly typed to the task model.
One of the parameters of the task is taskCreationUserID.

First i have a controller that gets as a parameter CurrentuserId

```
 public ActionResult CreateForEdit(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.AmountsId = new SelectList(db.Amounts1, "Id", "Interval");
            ViewBag.TaskStatusesId = new SelectList(db.TaskStatuses, "Id", "Status");
            ViewBag.TaskTypesId = new SelectList(db.TaskTypes, "Id", "Type");
            ViewBag.CreationUserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
            ViewBag.UserId = id;
            return View();
        }
```

That calls this view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Task</legend>
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
```

And so on...

and then i save this task using the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateForEdit(Task task)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                task.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                task.Piority = "p2";
                task.TaskStatusesId = 1;

                task.CreationUserID = UserId;
                db.Tasks.Add(task);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = UserId });
            }
```

The question is: how i put in the View the value of ViewBag.UserId so it will return to the controller as task.CreationUserID?

Comment: Is UserId a property of the Task object?

Comment: Yes, It is called CreationUserId in task object.

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag is available for one post back request at a time, you can use Session instead of View Bag

Answer (score 1):

Viewbag is just a dynamic object to hold data. there is no state management involved. what ever store in it will loose on postback.

> You have to add the UserId in the model and add a hidden field just like model.id

Comment: i have it in my model - it is called UserCreationId. how i put a value in it? What is the syntax?

Comment: @AlexandraOrlov you are not passing any model to View() still you are referring model in the view. There is some ambiguity in the example code. could you please provide the definition of model as well?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a UserId property on your Task object or that you can create one.

Don't put it in the ViewBag but instead create a new `Task` object in yout `HttpGet` method and assign the value of `id` to its property: `var task = new Task(); task.CreationUserID = id;`

Then pass the `Task` object to the View en store `task.CreationUserID` in a hidden field:  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreationUserID)`

In the `HttpPost` method you will find retrieve it from the task property `task.CreationUserID` 
so you can delete `task.CreationUserID = UserId;` from the `if statement`

Comment: I didnt understand. You want me in the controller function Create() - to call the View with task that have the value in CreationUSErID and then how in the view i assign this value to the model that is created?

Comment: you will need a hidden field in your view to store the value of id. Instead of storing it in the ViewBag store it in a property of your Task object. In order to have access to that property you need to create an obejct task in your CreateForEdit (httpget) action

Comment: what is the syntax for initializing this hidden field in the model?

Comment: see 3rd sentence in my answer: Then pass the Task object to the View en store task.CreationUserID in a hidden field: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreationUserID)